# OMXPlayer cookie for streaming

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer

I am trying to use OMXPlayer to request a stream from a URL, looking at the --cookie flag that is provided with OMXPlayer, I have tried doing something like this:

`omxplayer -o hdmi --cookie "cookie information" http://stream-url.com/`

It seems like the information after the cookie flag is a string, so I have tried entering the contents of a test cookie to see it shows up in the request made by OMXPlayer, but nothing is sent as a cookie in the request.
Here is where I found the documentation on the different flags: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/omxplayer.md

My question is if anyone has used the --cookie flag before in order to make a request like this successfully? Is there some kind of string formatting that I need to follow to get the cookie information to show up in the request made by OMXPlayer to the server?

Comment: run a test to see if any of the other parameters can be changed ... for example, try changing the `--user-agent` parameter

Comment: ```--user-agent``` doesn't seem to change anything either

Answer (score 0):

The value of omxplayer's cookie argument is passed on to ffmpeg. The format is [based on http's Set-Cookie header](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/6.0/http_8c_source.html#l01237), but appears to require a path attribute.

The following should work:

```
omxplayer --cookie "name=value; path=/" http://stream-url.com/
```